# Stop propagation not working - ul>li>ul>li - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a double open-close sidebar. Each li in the sidebar can have a list which can have a list themselves. An example:

```
<div class="list-panel">
    <ul>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/inphos/">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                <span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                <span class="nav-label">Administratie</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li class="group">
                    <a href="#">Abonnementen</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Abo-Orders</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">VoIPGrid</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">RoutIT</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The top li has the class "category". When I click on 1 level below, class "group", I do not want to slide the entire "category" up but open the list below "group" or redirect the user.

I am  trying to do this with the following:

```
$('.group').on('click', function(){
    console.log('group');
}).on('click','ul>li',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}).on('click','category',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.category').on('click',function(){
    console.log('category');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp(200);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

For some reason this piece of jQuerycode does not work properly, any ideas as to why?

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/bo4bkfzq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

breaking down this:-

```
$('.group').on('click', function(){
    console.log('group');
}).on('click','ul>li',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}).on('click','category',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

you can see here:-

```
$('.group').on('click','category',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

that this is looking for a `category` **element**, not **class** within `group`. which it will not find. changing `category` to `.category` will still not work because `category` is a parent of `group`.

try this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.category, .group').on('click',function(){
        console.log('category');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp(200);
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-family: Times;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-panel">
    <ul>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/inphos/">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                <span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="category active">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                <span class="nav-label">Administratie</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li class="group active">
                    <a href="#">Abonnementen</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Abo-Orders</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">VoIPGrid</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">RoutIT</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`return false;` will prevent the default event and stop it bubbling up.

Also, add the `active` class to `category` and `group` it they are starting as opened.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I understand more how it works!

Answer (score 1):

You never added e.stopPropagation() for `.group` elements, you just have the `console.log()`. Remember to add `e` as a parameter to the event function.

Additionally, you'll want to add the 'active' class to your lists at the start. Right now, it takes two clicks to get any noticeable change.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, I accidentally removed to much while trying to give a example piece of code :)